# sort list by date in android from json not from db

Tags: android

hi i am sorting the date from the webservices ie json and i need to sort that based on the created date.normal sort Collections.sort is not working i need to format the date before sort how to do that

```
CommunicationEngine.post(getApplicationContext(), "sports",
                    mylibraryRequest, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler#onStart()

    com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler#onSuccess(java.lang.String)

                        @Override

ObjectMapper sportsMapper = new ObjectMapper();## Heading ##try {
                                SportsResponse sportsResponse = sportsMapper.readValue(sportsResponseASString,SportsResponse.class);

if (null != sportsResponse) {
List<Assets> assets = sportsResponse.getAssets();
 (Assets asset : assets) {
//sort list
sort_sportList.add(asset.getTitle()
                                                .trim());
                                        if(asset.getSportType() != null){
                                            sort_sport.add(asset.getSportType().trim());                                        }                                                                           EGLibContent eglibitem = new EGLibContent(
                                                                                                    .getAssetEventDate(),

                                        adapter.getKey("Contents");
                                        adapter.addeglibcontent(eglibitem,ListView);
```

i use title normally by sorting collections.sort()

i want to sort getAssetEventDate(). the value returned from tthis function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to sort the List using getAssetEventDate()?
getAssetEventDate returns a number?

```
Collection.sort(assets, new Comparator<Asset>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Asset lhs, Asset rhs) {
            if (lhs.getAssetEventDate() < rhs.getAssetEventDate() {
                return -1;
            } else if (lhs.getAssetEventDate() > rhs.getAssetEventDate() {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
}
```